# Expand particular accordian by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have multiple accordian div like

```
<div class="accordion">
     <h3 style="width: 430px">Platform</h3>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
     <h3 style="width: 430px">Status</h3>
</div>
```

On ready I am setting

```
$(".accordion").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    animated: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,
    heightStyle: "content"
});
```

Now I want 1st Accordian to be expanded by default on load. I tried setting

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion( "option", "active", 1 );
```

But it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand the first accordion:

```
$(".accordion:first").accordion('option', 'active', 0);
```

Comment: What if I have to expand fifth div                                                                           $(".accordion:fifth").accordion('option', 'active',0) doesn't work

Comment: Then `$(".accordion:nth-child(5)")`.

Comment: You mean $(".accordion:nth-child(5)").accordion('option', 'active', 0)?

Comment: Yes. `:first` is a shortcut for `:nth-child(1)`. But this is the only shortcut for 1.

Comment: hmm.. Doesn't work. Also if do $(".accordion:first").accordion('option', 'active', 0); it opens the first div but $(".accordion:nth-child(1)").accordion('option', 'active', 0); opens all the divs.                                                  $(".accordion:nth-child(5)").accordion('option', 'active', 0) doesn't change anything

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Here is example of the first: http://jsfiddle.net/pzm5x1vb/, and here is the fifth: http://jsfiddle.net/pzm5x1vb/1/